# PHP File Upload Warning Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php

I am currently trying File Upload on PHP with security but I have this warning:

> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

I was able to get the file name with this:

```
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
```

This is the line that the warning indicates:

```
$file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
```

This line is to get the file extension of the uploaded file. Would you please help me fix this line? I will totally appreciate your help!

The file I used for testing is named "A.jpg"

Comment: Show your $file_name

Comment: I have added some information on my post @user1234

Comment: you can get the extension with this `$ext=pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can get file extension in this way:

```
<?php
$file_name = 'test_file_uploaded.abc.txt';
$file_ext = strtolower(substr($file_name, (strrpos($file_name, '.') + 1), strlen($file_name)));

echo $file_name; // output "test_file_uploaded.abc.txt"
echo $file_ext;  // output "txt"
?>
```